# Is there a way for using describe function in PySpark for more than one column?

Tags: select, pyspark, describe

I am trying to get some info from a dataset in PySpark and when I combine select function with describe function to see three columns details, the result just showing the last column's information.
I used a simple example from an article with this command:

```
my_data.select('Isball', 'Isboundary', 'Runs').describe().show()
```

and it should show me three columns details but it just show me this:

```
+-------+------------------+
|summary|              Runs|
+-------+------------------+
|  count|               605|
|   mean|0.9917355371900827|
| stddev| 1.342725481259329|
|    min|                 0|
|    max|                 6|
+-------+------------------+
```

what should I do to get the results that I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `describe` function works only on numeric and string columns as described in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.describe.html?highlight=describe#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.describe).

I'm assuming Isball and Isboundary are boolean columns thus their describe can't be seen. you can cast the columns to integer for it to work.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, True, "lorem"),
    (2, False, "ipsum")
], ["integer_col", "bool_col", "string_col"])

df.describe().show(truncate=0)

+-------+------------------+----------+
|summary|integer_col       |string_col|
+-------+------------------+----------+
|count  |2                 |2         |
|mean   |1.5               |null      |
|stddev |0.7071067811865476|null      |
|min    |1                 |ipsum     |
|max    |2                 |lorem     |
+-------+------------------+----------+


df.withColumn("bool_col", col("bool_col").cast("integer")).describe().show(truncate=0)

+-------+------------------+------------------+----------+
|summary|integer_col       |bool_col          |string_col|
+-------+------------------+------------------+----------+
|count  |2                 |2                 |2         |
|mean   |1.5               |0.5               |null      |
|stddev |0.7071067811865476|0.7071067811865476|null      |
|min    |1                 |0                 |ipsum     |
|max    |2                 |1                 |lorem     |
+-------+------------------+------------------+----------+
```